# Determination of export video runtime

Tags: export, animation, video

I have a huge simulation and tried to export it as a video file (or .gif). However regardlessly what I specify under the Framerate option the video its just running for 4 seconds (too fast). When I set the framerate to one the video just consists of one picture and if I set it to 100 the video is fluid but still only 4 seconds long.
Do I have to set another flag in the animation? While trying to present you some working example I came up with the following short lines:

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4Tuv8UKv", {"Data", All, {2, 3}}];
Animate[Graphics[Circle[data[[t]]],
      ImageSize -> {500, 200}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-5, 5}}, 
       Axes -> True], {t, Range[1, 1000]}, AnimationRate -> 1, 
       AnimationRunning -> False]

Export["test.mov", %, "FrameRate" -> 25]
```

So I thought that with setting the animation rate to 1 and the framerate to 25 I would get a 1000/25=40 seconds long video. Why is that not happening? Do I have to specify my frames somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't export animate, but just the list of frames. In other words, just replace `Animate` with `Table`, and remove the animate options. You can then export the list of frames as you do above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might as well write my comment as an answer.

Exporting a list of frames as a movie usually gives you much more control on the smoothness of the animation you are making.
since you have 1000 frames, if we export 1000 frames as a 25 fps, we get a 40 second movie.

```
   data = Import[
       "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4Tuv8UKv", {"Data", All, {2, 3}}];
   mymov = Table[
        Graphics[Circle[data[[t]]], ImageSize -> {500, 200}, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-5, 5}}, Axes -> True], {t, 
         Range[1, 1000]}];
   Export["test.mov", mymov, "FrameRate" -> 25]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was aiming for. Thank you!

Comment: Also I tend to use `ListAnimate` instead of `Animate` in the same way, it allows me to render the images first, in cases there is a mistake or error so I don't get stuck in an animate loop.